# Making rangy CSSClassApplier only toggle an element, not a class

Tags: javascript, html, range, rangy

Is there anyway/how can I make rangy's CSSClassApplier only toggle an element, not a class.

I tried:

```
var applier = rangy.createCssClassApplier(null, {
    elementTagName: 'strong'
});
```

But is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm afraid the CSS class applier revolves entirely around CSS classes so this won't work. There will be a more generic styling module in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I find there is a lot of golden rangy snippets you have made lying around SO, and Google Code. Ever thought of consolidating them into a wiki page or something?

Comment: @Petah: Yes, I've had a few requests for better documentation, so I'm planning to tackle that once I've finished version 1.3 of Rangy.